# Windows IOCP socket programming crash in windows 10 & 2012

Tags: windows, sockets, iocp

I am trying to help one of my customer to migrate a very old vc++ program which works on Windows 2003 as a win32 service to x64. It was compiled with VC 2005.

I have migrated to VC 2019 with windows SDK 10 & Windows 10.

There were few minor issues in DB and windows service ATL. I was able to fix them all.

Now there is a strange issue with the IOCP wherein the GetQueuedCompletionStatus results in success but the psobSockInfo and PerIoData results in unable to read error. (attached to the process in vs 2019 in debug mode).

```
bResult = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(sobIocpThParam->hReqRecThread,&BytesTransferred,(PDWORD_PTR)&psobSockInfo,(LPOVERLAPPED *) &PerIoData,INFINITE);
```

The code is written very similarly to this [example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/winsock/iocp/client/IocpClient.Cpp) and [the header file in line with](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/winsock/iocp/server/IocpServer.h)

I have tried to zero both the memory, tried to set the pointers to NULL. Nothing has helped. The bResult is 1. BytesTransfered is 177, The socket handle is valid.

Can any one point me in the right direction?

Comment: *the psobSockInfo and PerIoData results in unable to read error* - you mean that this pointers point to invalid memory location ? possible because corresponded `PER_IO_CONTEXT` and/or `PER_SOCKET_CONTEXT` already deleted. this code not use ref counting on objects and i be not say that code is good

Comment: The same code works if I choose it to be a win32 with the target set to 64bit.

Comment: *choose it to be a win32 with the target set to 64bit* - sorry, i not understand what you try set exactly. but if you the same src code work when compiled as 32 and crashed when compiled as 64 - this look like pointer truncation. say you  cast pointer to (ULONG) instead cast to (ULONG_PTR). until not enouth info for say what happens. i still have question about *the psobSockInfo and PerIoData results in unable to read error* - what you try say here